# Tensorflow seems to have problems with scientific notation

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

Since my network kept giving high loss and zero accuracy I have decided to look into the tensors that are going in it.

I have noticed that my normalizing function goes ok with decimal numbers but leaves scientific notation numbers as they are thus creating chaos with the samples.

After my simple normalization and batching, loaded from lists of filepaths and labels:

```
def _parse_image(imagepath, label):
    image_string = tf.read_file(imagepath)
    image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=3)
    image_resized = tf.image.resize_images(image_decoded, [img_size, img_size])
    image = image_resized * (1 / 255)
    return image, label

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dataset_train))
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_image)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
train_next = iterator.get_next()
```

And then

```
batch_x, batch_y = sess.run(train_next)
op, c = sess.run([optimiser, cross_entropy], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: np.expand_dims(batch_y, axis=-1)})
```

I get this is fed in feed_dict for decimals

```
[0.3425858  0.42196694 0.35618874]
[0.28829658 0.311826   0.311826  ]
[0.23520222 0.2508885  0.26069242]
```

And this for scientific notation

```
[7.11764753e-01 5.84313750e-01 7.27451026e-01]
[7.07843184e-01 5.68627477e-01 7.03921616e-01]
[7.08823562e-01 5.60784340e-01 7.23529458e-01]
```

Tried to do some transforms into float32 in a couple of points but it didn't work.

Comment: I don't understand, what are the inputs and the outputs, and why are they wrong? Also remember that scientific notation is just a way to show a number, the underlying representation doesn't change.

Comment: Inputs are tensors with RGB values from my pictures' dataset so I don't have a particular input at hand. The point is that it seems that input vectors that are read, say, as [128, 128, 128] are passed through * (1/255) to be [0.501, 0.501, 0.501]. Those that are input as [1.28e-02, 1.28e-02, 1.28e-02] remain the same instead of being transformed to [0.501, 0.501, 0.501].

Comment: In any case you need to provide actual code, inputs and outputs and explain why they are wrong, it is still not clear what the problem is.

Comment: Ok, I have edited in the block of the code that does the opeation. Thanks for your attention, let me know if there is anything else I should put here.

And the I think I've explained the input and output: input decimal does compute through the normalization * (1 / 255), input scientific does not compute.